# `controlTextDidEndEditing` gets fired when TextField becomes first responder

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder

I'm trying to detect when user finishes editing a `NSTextField` by implementing `NSTextFieldDelegate`'s `controlTextDidEndEditing:` method. However the problem is that upon initially making the `NSTextField` first responder of the window, immediately the `controlTextDidEndEditing:` notification gets fired. I tried this in an extremely simple test app and confirms the result. Would really appreciate some pointers on why this is the case and how to detect when textField loses focus.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the text field is first Responder, selectText: message will also sent to textField, which will cause it to end editing. If you don't want this behavior set NO to selectable property of textField.

```
- (void)selectText:(id)sender;
```

Ends editing and selects the entire contents of the receiver if it’s selectable.

Comment: What if it is desired to actually keep the textfield selectable? Also the testField is not the first responder initially. It becomes first responder and while becoming the first responder it sends `controlTextDidEndEditing` notification. Really puzzling

Comment: while its coming to firstResponder status, its being asked to select its text, so selectText: message is going to end the editing.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the `selectText:` message from being sent? Or `selectText:` directly without becoming first responder?

Comment: use setSelectable:NO on the textfield.

Comment: can you use `setSelectable:NO` before making first responder and change it back to YES afterwards? Since the textfield should actually be selectable.